# Tag wiki description cropped

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

The tag wiki "excerpt" for [soteriology](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soteriology) reads:

> How salvation is understood across different faiths

But the first three words are missing from the description as displayed on the Tags page:

[image]

Comment: Some background: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82700/new-tags-page-mangles-tag-wiki-excerpts/82702#82702

Comment: @balpha Thanks, useful insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, if you include "is" in the description, it will chop that word and everything before it.

This can be seen in the [bible](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bible) tag, [exegesis](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exegesis) tag, [jesus](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jesus) tag, etc.

I've changed the description to show correctly now.

Comment: Well found! Intriguing quirk of the system.